# Search multiple lists

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I want to search through my lists. And show it on a repeater control. On my dropdown i got 3 options, (All, List1 and List2). But my If statement wont work. The else is working fine, but it hangs when i click on "All". Any suggestions? My code below.

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://knowitintranet:9797/sites/News"))
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            if (DropDownListNewsFeed.SelectedItem.Value == "All")
            {
                SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                    query.Lists = "<Lists " +
                                  "ServerTemplate=\"10000\"" +
                                  "ServerTemplate=\"10001\"" +
                                  "ServerTemplate=\"10002\">" +
                                  "</Lists>";

                query.Query = string.Format("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>");
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";

                query.RowLimit = 10;

                DataTable dataTable = web.GetSiteData(query);

                RepeaterNewsFeed.DataSource = dataTable;

                RepeaterNewsFeed.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListNewsFeed.SelectedItem.Value);

                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
                query.RowLimit = 10;

                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

                RepeaterNewsFeed.DataSource = items;
                RepeaterNewsFeed.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you assigning `string.Format("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>");
` this to `query.Query`???

Comment: @Flowerking . My bad, don't know how it disappeared xD My bad!

Comment: What do you mean by "Hangs", did you manage to debug this, do you get any exceptions?

Comment: @Flowerking. Well it really don't hangs. It just don't give me any output when i select "All" in my dropdownselect. But when i select list1 or list2, it shows output without problems. I don't even get any exceptions and i've tried to debug, doesn't give me any answer..

Comment: @Flowerking, updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, but you should really check to see if this works..

What you get from `web.Lists.TryGetList("Staff News").ID` is a guid wrapped in {} like {Some Guid} eg. `{700de2ad-9bde-432b-b7a7-11fdc5168c4b}` So if you can take these Guids and strip the curly braces out before assigning them inside the xml for `"<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("Staff News").ID + " />"`. As this can cause problems with caml queries.

Just add .ToString() to the end as shown:

```
"<List ID=" + web.Lists.TryGetList("Staff News").ID.ToString()" />
```

Comment: So how should i change the code? Quite confused right now hehe.. It would be nice if you tried to take my code and change it here?

Comment: Updated the code, do you mean like that?

Comment: `web.Lists.TryGetList("Staff News").ID` will return guid.. change it to return string as shown. This will work.

Comment: "Redundant 'Object.ToString()' call for value type." is what i get now and i still don't get a output ;/

Comment: Thats strange! Object.ToString() for value type? I really don't get it. Can you try using the list ID's directly as you have shown just now and try to see if it works? Like I said I really don't see anything wrong with your code (unless I am wrong :( )

Comment: I've tried with my list IDs also.. Really don't know whats wrong. Maybe i've typed wrong in my if statement? Is if (DropDownListNewsFeed.SelectedItem.Value == "All") really right? ;o kinda confused atm.

Comment: You don't get this error -  
"Redundant 'Object.ToString()' call for value type if you are not inside the "if" right? Debugging will throw more light. try to step through the code execution if possible.

Comment: i'm getting the same error outside the if. But ill try to debug. Where should i put the breakpoint?

Comment: updated the code, i did have a exception but why didn't i get it? Annoying.. Check the commented line under query.Lists.

Comment: Good one, which means your one of your TryGetList() is not getting the named list you are looking for. This might be because there is no list with that name, or you do not have enough permissions to view the list, or you started the project as sandbox solution or you forgot to run visual studio as administrator or any of the above.. Thats how working with sharepoint is a mess :(

Comment: 1. The listnames are correctly. 2. It's my own server and i'm logged in as administrator. 3. It's not sandbox solution and 4. I'm running visual studio as administrator ;o

Comment: I am really sure one of your lists names might be wrong! You can debug it by checking which one of the 3 lines throwing error. Also, Is "management" spelt correct in your code or is the list name is like that?

Comment: Still not getting a output ;(

Comment: i did an trycatch in my event and got the following error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem'." .
Updated code also.

Comment: Thats because of this line `DataTable dataTable = web.GetSiteData(query);` this will return `SpListItemCollection`

Comment: so what should i try there instead?

Comment: When in doubt use `var`, or for this case simply use `SpListItemCollection `

Comment: but i'm not typing `SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListNewsFeed.SelectedItem.Value);` like i do on the else statement.. `SPListItemCollection items = web.GetSiteData(query);` doesn't work..

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think you are doing it right. Please ignore my previous comments. Please check the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery(v=office.12).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)